Terraform Backup for an Azure VM import not working as expected
I am trying to import Backup for an Azure VM for multiple vms and for some reason it's not reading the resource id for 1 VM correctly, I am passing the resource ID from an existing vm that is managed by terraform and I know the code works as I have imported other backups with out any issue. I tried deleting the backup from Azure portal and then getting terraform to create the backup. But my terraform plan is throwing the same error as before.

I tried importing using
`terraform import module.backup_protected_vm.azurerm_backup_protected_vm.backup_protected_vm[\`"arv-sandbox-canadacentral-vmtestifrsweb01\`"] "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-sandbox-abkup/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/arv-sandbox-canadacentral/backupFabrics/Azure/protectionContainers/iaasvmcontainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;rg-sandbox-web;vmtestifrsweb01/protectedItems/VM;iaasvmcontainerv2;rg-sandbox-web;vmtestifrsweb01"`

as well as
`terraform import module.backup_protected_vm.azurerm_backup_protected_vm.backup_protected_vm[\`"arv-sandbox-canadacentral-vmtestifrsweb01\`"] "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-sandbox-abkup/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/arv-sandbox-canadacentral/backupFabrics/Azure/protectionContainers/iaasvmcontainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;RG-SANDBOX-WEB;vmtestifrsweb01/protectedItems/VM;iaasvmcontainerv2;RG-SANDBOX-WEB;vmtestifrsweb01"`

Could someone help me understand where I am going wrong ?
My module is defined as below :
resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "backup_protected_vm" {
  for_each            = var.backup_protected_vms
  resource_group_name = each.value["resource_group_name"]
  recovery_vault_name = each.value["recovery_vault_name"]
  source_vm_id        = lookup(var.virtual_machine_ids, each.value["virtual_machine_variable_name"], null)
  backup_policy_id    = lookup(var.backup_policy_vm_ids, each.value["backup_policy_vm_variable_name"], null)
  protection_state    = each.value["protection_state"]
}

and my variable is defined as below :
variable "backup_protected_vms" {
  type = map(object({
    resource_group_name            = string
    recovery_vault_name            = string
    virtual_machine_variable_name  = string
    backup_policy_vm_variable_name = string
    protection_state               = string
  }))
}

My tfvars file looks like this :
backup_protected_vms = {
 arv-sandbox-canadacentral-vmtestifrsweb01 = {
     resource_group_name            = "rg-sandbox-abkup"                  
     recovery_vault_name            = "arv-sandbox-canadacentral" 
     virtual_machine_variable_name  = "vmtestifrsweb01" 
     backup_policy_vm_variable_name = "arv-sandbox-canadacentral-SixtyDayBackupPolicy"        
     protection_state               = "Protected"                  
   }
}


If the two IDs are truly identical and Terraform is still indicating that a replacement is necessary, Sometimes, running a state refresh can help: terraform refresh
if still same issue, remove and re-import the resource.

terraform state rm module.backup_protected_vm.azurerm_backup_protected_vm.backup_protected_vm["arv-sandbox-canadacentral-vmtestifrsweb01"]

@VenkatV I forgot to mention but I had tried that as well , the error still persists

It looks like there are some changes in the new Source VM ID. You can check both old and new IDs at https://www.diffchecker.com/. The replacement ID is showing the RG name in capital letters on the screen, while the old ID shows it in lower case. Terraform might consider this as a change

@VenkatV you are right there is a difference , I tried to import/ reimport using both values and I am getting the same problem, I am trying to figure out how to fix that, to be clear import is showing destroy when I tried  to import/ reimport using both values and I want to get a no change when I run plan.

Terraform will make a replacement only if there are changes in the code. For example, if you create a resource with the value A and then change it to B after creation, running terraform plan will indicate a force replacement to the new value.
I created a Recovery Services Vault with a backup item and then deleted the state file after creation. When I try to run terraform plan, I get an error saying that the resources (Recovery Services Vault, Backup Policy, and Protected VM) already exist and suggesting to import them.

Import azurerm_backup_protected_vm

After importing all resources, when I run terraform plan, I get the following result.


Note: While importing resources into Terraform, ensure that the values match the existing resources.

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "RG_Name"
}
data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "database-vm"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "example" {
  name                = "tfex-recovery-vault"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags
    ]
  }
}


resource "azurerm_backup_policy_vm" "example" {
  name                = "tfex-recovery-vault-policy"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.example.name

  backup {
    frequency = "Daily"
    time      = "23:00"
  }
  retention_daily {
    count = 10
  }
}
resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "vm1" {
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.example.name
  source_vm_id        = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  backup_policy_id    = azurerm_backup_policy_vm.example.id
}

After importing the resources, I deleted the backup from the portal. Then, when I ran terraform apply, it recreated the backup with the same configuration in the portal.


I didn't mention this in my question but I had done it the way you have but it was still throwing the same error, I tried deleting the backup through portal and creating the resource with terraform and for some reason terraform plan after that is still throwing the same result.

As a test, create a new backup with my code and delete the state file, then import with the same code and share the results.

the issue I am facing is that for some reason the state file and azure have resource/resource group name in different cases , and terraform is reading them as different resources , I am trying to solve this issue.
